# Globalizing application dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, globalization, resourcedictionary

In My application I have 2  Resource dictionaries (Spanish and English) that contains all strings of the application. In the main window I have a combobox from where the user can select their desired language. What I wanted to do is, when the user clicks on a specified language it should change the language of the entire application, not just the current window. I have searched here for a simple solution but couldn't find any. Can anyone suggest a way to achieve this?

Currently I use this way to change the current form's language

on the combobox selection changed event

```
private void Language_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ResourceDictionary dictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
    string lang = e.AddedItems[0].ToString();

    dictionary.Source = new Uri(@"/Resources/Languages/"+lang+".xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dictionary);
}
```

PS: I don't want to close and re open the window to the changes to be applied

Answer (score 0):

The [WPF Localization Extension](http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/) provides on-the-fly language changing without restarting the application.
Please note, that this approach uses `*.resx`-files for localization and not WPF specific `ResourceDictionaries`.

You can follow the common guides on the link above. Additionally, you can read through [this guide](http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/discussions/283041).

Comment: Tried it. the documentation is out dated and not working in VS2012. Used NuGet to add WPFLocalizeExtension to project. Followed everything in the official documentation also with no luck.

Comment: @barackomama The documentation is not out-dated. It's covering the latest release. I'm using the extension in my current WPF project. It works with VS2012 as well as VS2013. Did you take a look at the second link? **What** is not working?

Comment: oh, maybe I have done something wrong. Say if I have a button with key '@'Login and i have translated it in english and spanish in different resource files. During the design, I set DesignCulture="en-US" and it still shows '@'Login as button text. Same thing happens when I try to debug. And I cannot access my window in design mode because it says invalid Markup language. I tried running the test program provided by the author and I get the same thing

Comment: @barackomama I'm not sure about it, but maybe resx-file doesn't allow Keys with '@' in the beginning. Could you update your question by posting the xaml you used, as well as how you set the language now?

Comment: @barackomama Do you still have issues?

Comment: I have resolved it long time ago. Can't really recall what I did but I managed to get it work. Thank you for your assisstance. Really appreciate it.